# Where can I find the configure options used to build a package?

Tags: compiling, source-code

I need to install asterisk 1.6.2.18 on Ubuntu 10.10

I would like to know what the configure options were that were used to generate the ubuntu package of asterisk 1.6.2.7.

My favorite server distro is Slackware and on that I just reference the Slackbuild file to find out how a package was made and possibly customised in order to remake it with a newer source, but I cannot figure this out on Ubuntu. I am under time pressure now, so I would appreciate some pointers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 47):

The easiest thing to do may be to look at the build logs for the package in question. You can find them by starting at, e.g., https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/asterisk, then follow the link for the version you care about (in this case, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/asterisk/1:1.6.2.7-1ubuntu1.1)

Under the "Builds" header, you'll see a link for each architecture the package was built on. Don't worry about this too much, and just pick one - I'll look at amd64.

On the build record page, there's a link to the buildlog - https://launchpadlibrarian.net/62593317/buildlog_ubuntu-maverick-amd64.asterisk_1%3A1.6.2.7-1ubuntu1.1_BUILDING.txt.gz

And if you search the log for "./configure", you'll find this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/build/buildd/asterisk-1.6.2.7/debian/dummyprogs ./configure \
        --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man \
        --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info \
        --with-cap \
        --with-gsm \
        --with-imap=system \
        --with-pwlib=/usr/share/pwlib/include/ \
        --with-h323=/usr/share/openh323/
```

Answer (score 11):

I think that you won't be able to see the configure options from the binary (.deb) package.
You can just find some information regarding the dependencies involved by using:

`apt-cache showpkg asterisk`

If you need to check the configure options, i think you should download the source files by typing:

`apt-get source asterisk`

and then check for the information you need in the `debian/rules` file.

Comment: Thanks for that. I see all the patches now that were applied, but I don't see the actual configure command used anywhere in the files retrieved by apt-get source asterisk. That's not necesarily important for this package, but in general it is something I would like to know.

Comment: As @Pavlos G. said, see in the file `asterisk-1.6.2.9/debian/rules`, go to line 61.

Comment: And `dpkg -l | grep something` if you forgot the package name.