# How can I know which options have been passed to ./configure while compiling / building a Debian package?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, source-packages

**To close voters**: This question is different from the question linked, because its scope is to find the options passed to ./configure during the building of a generic Debian package, not only to find the options passed to ./configure during the building of the Debian packages available in the repositories.

As the title said, I've unpacked a Debian package in order to recompile / rebuild it adding a custom option, but I can't sort out how to find the options passed to ./configure when the package was compiled / built in first place. Is finding such options feasible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the configure options used to build a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48499/where-can-i-find-the-configure-options-used-to-build-a-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible in a fully general sense, but if your deb came from Debian or Ubuntu directly (*i.e.*, not a third-party deb), then it is required to be reproducible by autobuilders which do something like the following:

- Start with a bare system- all Essential: yes or Priority: Required packages, plus build-essential, and any extra dependencies of these
- Satisfy the build-depends and build-conflicts of the package to be built
- Also satisfy build-depends-indep and build-conflicts-indep if appropriate, as determined by build type
- Run `debuild`

You can read the precise steps that `debuild` takes in its man page, but the parts you probably care about are

- `debian/rules build`  (this should do all the configuration and building)
- `fakeroot debian/rules binary` (this should "install" the built package into a directory tree which will be assembled into the final deb)

tl;dr: If the package build procedure did any `./configure`-ing at all, you should find it in `debian/rules`.