# Is there a way to know how certain apt packages are built?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to build some local packages (just trying to be smart...) but it seems like using the provided one from `apt` works while my compiled version doesn't.

Hence, I'm trying to reverse engineer and see how each of the library is being built and pushed onto `apt`. To use a specific sample, I'm trying to build my local `blas` and `lapack` for my work. The version coming with `bionic` [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libblas-dev) is only 3.7.1 while I'm trying to get up-to-date using [3.8.0](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).

Any hints where I can poke around?

Comment: Possibly related: [Where can I find the configure options used to build a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48499/where-can-i-find-the-configure-options-used-to-build-a-package)

Comment: lapack is a *source* package, not a *binary* package in the Ubuntu repositories. It's not 'built' at all.